# Using a regex to match a word ending in a comma but not within another word

Tags: java, regex

I want to use a regex to achieve two objectives: match a string only when it is a complete word (don't match "on" inside of "contact"), and match strings that end with a comma or period.

This is an example. It is meant to find the string (str2) in str and replace it with the same string surrounded by parenthesis.

```
while(scan2.hasNext()) {
    String str2 = scan2.next();
    str = str.replaceAll("\\b" + str2 + "\\b", "(" + str2 + ")");
}
```

It does avoid matching strings within words, but it ignores strings that end in a comma or period.

How would I do this?

Comment: How about adding `[.,]?` at the end of your regex?

Comment: As always with text-matching questions, besides explaining the goal, please also give us several example inputs and the desired output (which part should be matched). It would also be helpful if you tell us, for that inputs, what your current program matches.

Comment: Your code does not ignore strings that end in a comma or period. The replacement does ignore the commas and dots so you get `(str2),` or `(str2).`

Comment: I tried [,.]? but it ignored everything ending with a comma. So, c0mpu73rs, is supposed to change to (c0mpu73rs,) but it remains c0mpu73rs,. This is true for everything ending with a comma.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(replace("upon contact", "on"));
        System.out.println(replace("upon contact,", "contact"));
        System.out.println(replace("upon contact", "contact"));
    }

    private static String replace(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.replaceAll(String.format("\\b(%s)\\b(?=[.,])", s2), "\\($1\\)");
    }
}
```

> upon contact // matches only complete words
>
> upon (contact), // replaces match with (match)
>
> upon contact // only matches if ends with , or .

Answer (score 0):

The following regex matches string ending with comma/period or string composed by a single complete word:

```
(?s)(^(?<A>\b\w+\b)$)|((?s)^(?<B>.+(?<=[,.]))$)
```

See also https://regex101.com/r/E78rQV/1/ for more explanations.

Answer (score -1):

I took the liberty of adding exclamation point and question mark.
Brackets means it will match for any of the characters inside the brackets.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\b" + str2 + "[\\b.,!?]", "(" + str2 + ")");
```

Comment: It should throw a runtime exception at `[\\b`.